# Install Safari 7 from Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, safari

I am currently running Mountain Lion and have Safari 6.2. I need to upgrade Safari to version 7 to run some tests for a particular application. However, in order to upgrade Safari I need to upgrade to Mavericks.

Unfortunately, that is easier said than done since Yosemite just came out. I did some checking and found that Yosemite is running Safari 8, which will not work for the tests I need to run.

Are any of the following options possible?

1. Get Safari installed on Mountain Lion
2. Upgrade from Mountain Lion to Mavericks
3. Upgrade to Yosemite and then downgrade Safari to version 7

Update:
I do need it to actually be Safari 7 for my tests. Is there any (non-shady) website that I can still get Mavericks from?

Comment: Do you need the browser to actually be Safari 7, or do you need it to masquerade itself as Safari 7 to a server? Without intervention from Apple, an upgrade to Mavericks does not seem to be possible at this point.

Answer (score 3):

1) No. Safari requires libraries and frameworks that will only be found in Mavericks. You can potentially snag the Safari.app from someone runnin v7 on OS X 10.9, but I'm fairly certain it will simply crash on launch due to the requirements mentioned above.

2) Yes you can still install Mavericks provided you have purchased it from the Mac App Store. It will be listed under your Purchases tab.

3) No. You will likely suffer the same discrepancies mentioned in 1) with a version mismatch.

Comment: I was able to run Safari 7.04, 7.1 and 7.1.8 on OS X 8.4. I didn't try out all the features but none of the versions crashed on startup.

Answer (score 2):

You may not be able to downgrade to Safari 7 after upgrading OSX, but you can still view a webpage with Web Inspector and I'm developer mode as if it were being viewed in Safari 7:

[image]

[image]

More info here:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6656158?start=0&tstart=0